# Create Database (not tables) on remote host using vb.net in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, vb.net, remote-access

I am building a CRM app using **vb.net in asp.net**. My app is still on my local machine, but I intend to deploy it later when it's finished.

At the other hand, I have a hosting plan that gives me unlimited MySQL databases where I created a database for my app to use.

My app connects to the database, writes and reads info from it with no problem. it also creates new tables for each new Customer (each user has 9 tables in database that contain his info).

After adding a few customers, the database gets messy, containing dozens of tables in one place.

As a solution for that, I thought it will be more clear, tidy and secure if I can ***create a seperate DB for each user/customer*** from my app.

Is there a way to do this using vb.net and asp.net? If so, could you provide some sample code that can achieve this?

Comment: Why would you create new databases for each customer? Why would you create seperate tables for seperate customers? Normally you have a table that holds customers and other tables with related data like orders, invoices, ... depends on the domain. You have normalization for your tables and keys/foreign keys to ty them together. Please show DDL and tell a little more about what you model. I find a server hosting maybe thousands databases (one for every customer) messy. It would make any reporting difficult, you'd have to join data over DBs - possible but impractical.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for you answer.
I Understand what you said, but still want to do it. Have you any code how to do it.

Comment: What you are suggesting goes way beyond bad. If you think it's a good idea then I don't think that you understand how a database works. There is absolutely no way that you should be creating new databases or tables or even columns after deployment. You add rows only. Each time you have a new customer, you add a new row to the Customer table. That's it. The only time the schema changes is when there's a fundamental change to how your app works. Learn how databases work and do it properly. If you go down the path you suggest then your in for a world of pain later. It's for your own good.

Comment: Have you tried using the SQL statement `CREATE DATABASE databasename`